# Vagrant Provisioning Error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vagrant, vagrantfile

I was following the [Vagrant Tutorial](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/provisioning.html) for provisioning Apache through Vagrant and I am getting the following error as an output when executing **vagrant reload --provision** command - [Vagrant Provisioning Error Output](https://gist.github.com/fardeenrahaman/aae5fc5f42a4f6eb3363)

Could you please advise where I might be going wrong? I have modified the Vagrantfile correctly as per the guide. Please see below:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

I am running Vagrant through VirtualBox on Mavericks 10.9.5.

Comment: Link to the error isn't working for me.

Comment: Hi Hassan, I have modified the error link. Please have a look now.

Comment: Can you show your bootstrap.sh file

Comment: Hi @Greg, here is the bootstap.sh file [link](https://gist.github.com/fardeenrahaman/79ef7e69fd976828f414)

Comment: I tried the following commands and observed the same issue again
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
sudo su -
apt-get update

I have added the output of the network settings of my vagrant [here](https://gist.github.com/fardeenrahaman/a2f3f0ed25bc8fbfcc0f)

Comment: In addition to the above, I tried editing the Vagrantfile by adding the following line `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080`, as I noticed that in the Virtual Box network adapter settings only the SSH forwarding was being displayed. 

After adding port 8080, it did appear in the Virtual Box network adapter settings, but there was no difference in the connectivity. I still keep getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem.

The issue was related to the DNS cache which was populated with the DNS table of the VPN software I was running on my Macbook.

I rebooted my Macbook and the issue was resolved immediately as the DNS cache was reset.

I looked up online later and found that a hard reset such as rebooting the laptop was not necessary, although it is the standard practice followed by most when troubleshooting such issues in the presence of a VPN software.

One can also do a soft reset by flushing the DNS. There is a good tutorial as how one can do this on Windows, Mac or Linux on [Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Flush-DNS)

Answer (score 0):

Your Vagrant box does not appear to be able to connect to the internet to run the Ubuntu updates.

You may want to set the VM up to use NAT or a Bridged mode networking based on your host device's configuration requirements. Also, any proxies as required by your network to reach the outside world.

Comment: Hi @Leon, please see my comments above regarding the connectivity issues.